# If Lie(H) preserves a subspace, must H also preserve that subspace?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Assume $H \subset G$ is a closed connected subgroup of a linear algebraic group over an arbitrary field (both assumed to be smooth). Assume $G$ acts linearly on the (finite dimensional) vector space $V$. The action $\sigma : G \times V \to V$ induces the differential $d\sigma: Lie(G) \times V \to V$.

> If $Lie(H)$ preserves a subspace $W \subset V$ (that is, $d\alpha(Lie(H) \times W) \subset W$), must $H$ also preserve $W$ (that is, $\sigma(H \times W)\subset W$)?

And if there are counter-examples, what further assumptions on $H$ and $G$ would make this statement true?

Comment: The statement is true if $H$ is connected (and obviously false otherwise). It doesn't matter what the ambient group $G$ is (because you can identify $H$ with the closure of its image in $GL(V)$ under $\sigma$).

Comment: Okay, do you have a reference, or proof? (Notice I assumed connected in the question)